# How to make one page navigation smoothly on Ipad?

Tags: jquery, html, css

One page navigation website is a trend, and I want to make one but I always encounter a problem with ipad. Webpage usually can scroll smoothly on my macbook , but it is awful on ipad, even only with some pictures and css. Here an example, http://jsfiddle.net/fatdogmark/YxH8r/ , very choppy when moving on ipad. I think Ipad 4 is already the highest performance in all kind of tablets, but the performance is still horrible. Is it Ipad not suitable for one page navigation website? I hope I can get some advices here.
Are there any tricks or technique to boost ipads performance? like don't use `overflow` , do not embed a lot  of css or js `<script src=''></script>` all in the header(that's what I usually do),put them html inline or put them all in one same file? or use some kind of codes like translate3D(0,0,0)?Or avoid to use transition , jquery animations or easing? Or are there better performance navigation plugins?

Also I accidently discovered that on Ipad zooming will actually activated `$(window).resize(function(){//});` ...so I disable all window.resize on my script to save performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this
`$btn1.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px, " + anchor1_pos + "px, 0px)";`
and it is significantly better than any other transition.

Obviously you'll have to set its `webkitTransition` as well, e.g. `"all ease-in-out 2s"`

Also, in my experience, you should make sure that your DOM wont grow toooo much. If you are planning on having a lot of content, you should consider hiding unused pages with `"display: none"`. But since you want to scroll on just 1 page, which makes me think that you have a limited amount of information, you should be fine I think. And this worked for me on iPad1 & 2 ;)

Comment: But isn't if using translated3d, the default scroll bar will not match?I'll need to use the scroll bar.

Comment: also display:hidden the already scrolled section? It needs to keep check user scrolling will even take more resources